# Nativescript Migrate from version 5.4.2 to version 6

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-angular

I was trying to **migrate native script project from current version 5.4.2 to version 6**. Below are the details of how I encountered this issue.
I have also raised a github issue [here](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/8303) to NativeScript Team.

Is there any step I missed while migrating?

---

**Steps To Reproduce**

1. I have updated nativescript version 5.4.2 to nativescript@latest
2. Executed "tns migrate"
3. Executed "tns run"
4. Updated modules "@angular/fire", "node-sass"
5. Added @ViewChild in each component to resolve parameter errors for {static:true/false}

**Environment**
[Details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U9nUa.png)

```
nativescript has 6.3.3 version
tns-core-modules version is 6.0.1
tns-android version is 6.0.0
tns-ios version is 6.0.1
```

**Got the following error at main thread**

> ```
> System.err: Caused by: com.tns.NativeScriptException: Calling js method onCreate failed
> System.err: Error: Main entry is missing. App cannot be started. Verify app bootstrap.
> ```

**Build Error**

```
Searching for devices...
Preparing project...
File change detected. Starting incremental webpack compilation...

webpack is watching the files…

Hash: 72c4bbbdd2050c099283
Version: webpack 4.30.0
Time: 10812ms
Built at: 02/03/2020 12:37:41 PM
                   Asset       Size   Chunks             Chunk Names
assets\browser_icons.png   60.6 KiB           [emitted]  
        assets\error.png   9.17 KiB           [emitted]  
  assets\icon-sprite.png     33 KiB           [emitted]  
  assets\logo-sprite.png   6.39 KiB           [emitted]  
  assets\no-question.png   5.42 KiB           [emitted]  
               bundle.js   7.07 KiB   bundle  [emitted]  bundle
            package.json  164 bytes           [emitted]  
              runtime.js   71.4 KiB  runtime  [emitted]  runtime
     tns-java-classes.js    0 bytes           [emitted]  
               vendor.js   3.58 MiB   vendor  [emitted]  vendor
Entrypoint bundle = runtime.js vendor.js bundle.js
[./app.css] 940 bytes {bundle} [built]
[./main.ts] 1.17 KiB {bundle} [built]
[./package.json] 157 bytes {bundle} [optional] [built]
    + 172 hidden modules

ERROR in node_modules/face-api.js/build/commonjs/ageGenderNet/AgeGenderNet.d.ts(20,15): error TS2416: Property 'extractParamsFromWeigthMap' in type 'AgeGenderNet' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'NeuralNetwork<NetParams>'.
  Type '(weightMap: import("D:/am workspace/codemeet-frontend - Copy/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/tensor_types").NamedTensorMap) => { params: import("D:/am workspace/codemeet-frontend - Copy/node_modules/face-api.js/build/commonjs/ageGenderNet/types").NetParams; paramMappings: import("D:/am workspace/codemeet-fro...' is not assignable to type '(weightMap: import("D:/am workspace/codemeet-frontend - Copy/node_modules/tfjs-image-recognition-base/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/tensor_types").NamedTensorMap) => { ...; }'.
    Types of parameters 'weightMap' and 'weightMap' are incompatible.
      Type 'import("D:/am workspace/codemeet-frontend - Copy/node_modules/tfjs-image-recognition-base/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/tensor_types").NamedTensorMap' is not assignable to type 'import("D:/am workspace/codemeet-frontend - Copy/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/tensor_types").NamedTensorMap'.
node_modules/face-api.js/build/commonjs/faceFeatureExtractor/FaceFeatureExtractor.d.ts(9,15): error TS2416: Property 'extractParamsFromWeigthMap' in type 'FaceFeatureExtractor' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'IFaceFeatureExtractor<FaceFeatureExtractorParams>'. 
  Type '(weightMap: import("D:/am workspace/codemeet-frontend - Copy/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/tensor_types").NamedTensorMap) => { params: import("D:/am workspace/codemeet-frontend - Copy/node_modules/face-api.js/build/commonjs/faceFeatureExtractor/types").FaceFeatureExtractorParams; paramMappings: import("D:/...' is not assignable to type '(weightMap: import("D:/am workspace/codemeet-frontend - Copy/node_modules/tfjs-image-recognition-base/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/tensor_types").NamedTensorMap) => { ...; }'.
node_modules/face-api.js/build/commonjs/faceFeatureExtractor/FaceFeatureExtractor.d.ts(9,15): error TS2416: Property 'extractParamsFromWeigthMap' in type 'FaceFeatureExtractor' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'NeuralNetwork<FaceFeatureExtractorParams>'.
  Type '(weightMap: import("D:/am workspace/codemeet-frontend - Copy/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/tensor_types").NamedTensorMap) => { params: import("D:/am workspace/codemeet-frontend - Copy/node_modules/face-api.js/build/commonjs/faceFeatureExtractor/types").FaceFeatureExtractorParams; paramMappings: import("D:/...' is not assignable to type '(weightMap: import("D:/am workspace/codemeet-frontend - Copy/node_modules/tfjs-image-recognition-base/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/tensor_types").NamedTensorMap) => { ...; }'.
    Types of parameters 'weightMap' and 'weightMap' are incompatible.
      Type 'import("D:/am workspace/codemeet-frontend - Copy/node_modules/tfjs-image-recognition-base/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/tensor_types").NamedTensorMap' is not assignable to type 'import("D:/am workspace/codemeet-frontend - Copy/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/tensor_types").NamedTensorMap'.
        Index signatures are incompatible.
          Type 'import("D:/am workspace/codemeet-frontend - Copy/node_modules/tfjs-image-recognition-base/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/tensor").Tensor<import("D:/am workspace/codemeet-frontend - Copy/node_modules/tfjs-image-recognition-base/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/types").Rank>' is not assignable to type 'import("D:/am workspace/codemeet-frontend - Copy/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/tensor").Tensor<import("D:/am workspace/codemeet-frontend - Copy/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/types").Rank>'.
            Types of property 'flatten' are incompatible.
              Type '() => import("D:/am workspace/codemeet-frontend - Copy/node_modules/tfjs-image-recognition-base/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/tensor").Tensor<import("D:/am workspace/codemeet-frontend - Copy/node_modules/tfjs-image-recognition-base/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/types").Rank.R1>' is not assignable to type '() => import("D:/am workspace/codemeet-frontend - Copy/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/tensor").Tensor<import("D:/am workspace/codemeet-frontend - Copy/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/types").Rank.R1>'.
                Type 'import("D:/am workspace/codemeet-frontend - Copy/node_modules/tfjs-image-recognition-base/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/tensor").Tensor<import("D:/am workspace/codemeet-frontend - Copy/node_modules/tfjs-image-recognition-base/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/types").Rank.R1>' is not assignable to type 'import("D:/am workspace/codemeet-frontend - Copy/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/tensor").Tensor<import("D:/am workspace/codemeet-frontend - Copy/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/types").Rank.R1>'.
                  Types of property 'asScalar' are incompatible.
                    Type '() => import("D:/am workspace/codemeet-frontend - Copy/node_modules/tfjs-image-recognition-base/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/tensor").Tensor<import("D:/am workspace/codemeet-frontend - Copy/node_modules/tfjs-image-recognition-base/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/types").Rank.R0>' is not assignable to type '() => import("D:/am workspace/codemeet-frontend - Copy/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/tensor").Tensor<import("D:/am workspace/codemeet-frontend - Copy/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/types").Rank.R0>'.
                      Type 'import("D:/am workspace/codemeet-frontend - Copy/node_modules/tfjs-image-recognition-base/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/tensor").Tensor<import("D:/am workspace/codemeet-frontend - Copy/node_modules/tfjs-image-recognition-base/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/types").Rank.R0>' is not assignable to type 'import("D:/am workspace/codemeet-frontend - Copy/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/tensor").Tensor<import("D:/am workspace/codemeet-frontend - Copy/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/types").Rank.R0>'.   
                        Types of property 'as2D' are incompatible.
                          Type '(rows: number, columns: number) => import("D:/am workspace/codemeet-frontend - Copy/node_modules/tfjs-image-recognition-base/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/tensor").Tensor<import("D:/am workspace/codemeet-frontend - Copy/node_modules/tfjs-image-recognition-base/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/types"...' is not assignable to type '(rows: number, columns: number) => import("D:/am workspace/codemeet-frontend - Copy/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/tensor").Tensor<import("D:/am workspace/codemeet-frontend - Copy/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/types").Rank.R2>'.
                            Type 'import("D:/am workspace/codemeet-frontend - Copy/node_modules/tfjs-image-recognition-base/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/tensor").Tensor<import("D:/am workspace/codemeet-frontend - Copy/node_modules/tfjs-image-recognition-base/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/types").Rank.R2>' is not assignable to type 'import("D:/am workspace/codemeet-frontend - Copy/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/tensor").Tensor<import("D:/am workspace/codemeet-frontend - Copy/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/types").Rank.R2>'.
                              Types of property 'asType' are incompatible.
                                Type '<T extends import("D:/am workspace/codemeet-frontend - Copy/node_modules/tfjs-image-recognition-base/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/tensor").Tensor<import("D:/am workspace/codemeet-frontend - Copy/node_modules/tfjs-image-recognition-base/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/types").Rank.R2>>(this: T, dty...' is not assignable to type '<T extends import("D:/am workspace/codemeet-frontend - Copy/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/tensor").Tensor<import("D:/am workspace/codemeet-frontend - Copy/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/types").Rank.R2>>(this: T, dtype: "string" | ... 3 more ... | "complex64") => T'.
                                  The 'this' types of each signature are incompatible.
                                    Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'Tensor<Rank.R2>'.
                                      Type 'Tensor<Rank.R2>' is missing the following properties from type 'Tensor<Rank.R2>': bytes, divNoNan, relu6
node_modules/face-api.js/build/commonjs/faceFeatureExtractor/TinyFaceFeatureExtractor.d.ts(9,15): error TS2416: Property 'extractParamsFromWeigthMap' in type 'TinyFaceFeatureExtractor' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'IFaceFeatureExtractor<TinyFaceFeatureExtractorParams>'.
  Type '(weightMap: import("D:/am workspace/codemeet-frontend - Copy/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/tensor_types").NamedTensorMap) => { params: import("D:/am workspace/codemeet-frontend - Copy/node_modules/face-api.js/build/commonjs/faceFeatureExtractor/types").TinyFaceFeatureExtractorParams; paramMappings: import(...' is not assignable to type '(weightMap: import("D:/am workspace/codemeet-frontend - Copy/node_modules/tfjs-image-recognition-base/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/tensor_types").NamedTensorMap) => { ...; }'.
node_modules/face-api.js/build/commonjs/faceFeatureExtractor/TinyFaceFeatureExtractor.d.ts(9,15): error TS2416: Property 'extractParamsFromWeigthMap' in type 'TinyFaceFeatureExtractor' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'NeuralNetwork<TinyFaceFeatureExtractorParams>'.
  Type '(weightMap: import("D:/am workspace/codemeet-frontend - Copy/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/tensor_types").NamedTensorMap) => { params: import("D:/am workspace/codemeet-frontend - Copy/node_modules/face-api.js/build/commonjs/faceFeatureExtractor/types").TinyFaceFeatureExtractorParams; paramMappings: import(...' is not assignable to type '(weightMap: import("D:/am workspace/codemeet-frontend - Copy/node_modules/tfjs-image-recognition-base/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/tensor_types").NamedTensorMap) => { ...; }'.
    Types of parameters 'weightMap' and 'weightMap' are incompatible.
      Type 'import("D:/am workspace/codemeet-frontend - Copy/node_modules/tfjs-image-recognition-base/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/tensor_types").NamedTensorMap' is not assignable to type 'import("D:/am workspace/codemeet-frontend - Copy/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/tensor_types").NamedTensorMap'.
node_modules/face-api.js/build/commonjs/faceProcessor/FaceProcessor.d.ts(19,15): error TS2416: Property 'extractParamsFromWeigthMap' in type 
'FaceProcessor<TExtractorParams>' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'NeuralNetwork<NetParams>'.
  Type '(weightMap: import("D:/am workspace/codemeet-frontend - Copy/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/tensor_types").NamedTensorMap) => { params: import("D:/am workspace/codemeet-frontend - Copy/node_modules/face-api.js/build/commonjs/faceProcessor/types").NetParams; paramMappings: import("D:/am workspace/codemeet-fr...' is not assignable to type '(weightMap: import("D:/am workspace/codemeet-frontend - Copy/node_modules/tfjs-image-recognition-base/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/tensor_types").NamedTensorMap) => { ...; }'.
    Types of parameters 'weightMap' and 'weightMap' are incompatible.
      Type 'import("D:/am workspace/codemeet-frontend - Copy/node_modules/tfjs-image-recognition-base/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/tensor_types").NamedTensorMap' is not assignable to type 'import("D:/am workspace/codemeet-frontend - Copy/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/tensor_types").NamedTensorMap'.
node_modules/face-api.js/build/commonjs/faceRecognitionNet/FaceRecognitionNet.d.ts(10,15): error TS2416: Property 'extractParamsFromWeigthMap' in type 'FaceRecognitionNet' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'NeuralNetwork<NetParams>'.
  Type '(weightMap: import("D:/am workspace/codemeet-frontend - Copy/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/tensor_types").NamedTensorMap) => { params: import("D:/am workspace/codemeet-frontend - Copy/node_modules/face-api.js/build/commonjs/faceRecognitionNet/types").NetParams; paramMappings: import("D:/am workspace/codeme...' is not assignable to type '(weightMap: import("D:/am workspace/codemeet-frontend - Copy/node_modules/tfjs-image-recognition-base/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/tensor_types").NamedTensorMap) => { ...; }'.
    Types of parameters 'weightMap' and 'weightMap' are incompatible.
      Type 'import("D:/am workspace/codemeet-frontend - Copy/node_modules/tfjs-image-recognition-base/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/tensor_types").NamedTensorMap' is not assignable to type 'import("D:/am workspace/codemeet-frontend - Copy/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/tensor_types").NamedTensorMap'.
node_modules/face-api.js/build/commonjs/mtcnn/Mtcnn.d.ts(17,15): error TS2416: Property 'extractParamsFromWeigthMap' in type 'Mtcnn' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'NeuralNetwork<NetParams>'.
  Type '(weightMap: import("D:/am workspace/codemeet-frontend - Copy/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/tensor_types").NamedTensorMap) => { params: import("D:/am workspace/codemeet-frontend - Copy/node_modules/face-api.js/build/commonjs/mtcnn/types").NetParams; paramMappings: 
import("D:/am workspace/codemeet-frontend -...' is not assignable to type '(weightMap: import("D:/am workspace/codemeet-frontend - Copy/node_modules/tfjs-image-recognition-base/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/tensor_types").NamedTensorMap) => { ...; }'.
    Types of parameters 'weightMap' and 'weightMap' are incompatible.
      Type 'import("D:/am workspace/codemeet-frontend - Copy/node_modules/tfjs-image-recognition-base/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/tensor_types").NamedTensorMap' is not assignable to type 'import("D:/am workspace/codemeet-frontend - Copy/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/tensor_types").NamedTensorMap'.
node_modules/face-api.js/build/commonjs/ssdMobilenetv1/SsdMobilenetv1.d.ts(18,15): error TS2416: Property 'extractParamsFromWeigthMap' in type 'SsdMobilenetv1' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'NeuralNetwork<NetParams>'.
  Type '(weightMap: import("D:/am workspace/codemeet-frontend - Copy/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/tensor_types").NamedTensorMap) => { params: import("D:/am workspace/codemeet-frontend - Copy/node_modules/face-api.js/build/commonjs/ssdMobilenetv1/types").NetParams; paramMappings: import("D:/am workspace/codemeet-f...' is not assignable to type '(weightMap: import("D:/am workspace/codemeet-frontend - Copy/node_modules/tfjs-image-recognition-base/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/tensor_types").NamedTensorMap) => { ...; }'.
    Types of parameters 'weightMap' and 'weightMap' are incompatible.
      Type 'import("D:/am workspace/codemeet-frontend - Copy/node_modules/tfjs-image-recognition-base/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/tensor_types").NamedTensorMap' is not assignable to type 'import("D:/am workspace/codemeet-frontend - Copy/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/tensor_types").NamedTensorMap'.
node_modules/face-api.js/build/commonjs/tinyFaceDetector/TinyFaceDetector.d.ts(9,15): error TS2416: Property 'extractParamsFromWeigthMap' in 
type 'TinyFaceDetector' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'TinyYolov2'.
  Type '(weightMap: import("D:/am workspace/codemeet-frontend - Copy/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/tensor_types").NamedTensorMap) => { params: import("D:/am workspace/codemeet-frontend - Copy/node_modules/tfjs-image-recognition-base/build/commonjs/tinyYolov2/types").TinyYolov2NetParams; paramMappings: import("D:/a...' is not assignable to type '(weightMap: import("D:/am workspace/codemeet-frontend - Copy/node_modules/tfjs-image-recognition-base/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/tensor_types").NamedTensorMap) => { ...; }'.
    Types of parameters 'weightMap' and 'weightMap' are incompatible.
      Type 'import("D:/am workspace/codemeet-frontend - Copy/node_modules/tfjs-image-recognition-base/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/tensor_types").NamedTensorMap' is not assignable to type 'import("D:/am workspace/codemeet-frontend - Copy/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/tensor_types").NamedTensorMap'.
node_modules/face-api.js/build/commonjs/tinyYolov2/TinyYolov2.d.ts(10,15): error TS2416: Property 'extractParamsFromWeigthMap' in type 'TinyYolov2' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'TinyYolov2'.
  Type '(weightMap: import("D:/am workspace/codemeet-frontend - Copy/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/tensor_types").NamedTensorMap) => { params: import("D:/am workspace/codemeet-frontend - Copy/node_modules/tfjs-image-recognition-base/build/commonjs/tinyYolov2/types").TinyYolov2NetParams; paramMappings: import("D:/a...' is not assignable to type '(weightMap: import("D:/am workspace/codemeet-frontend - Copy/node_modules/tfjs-image-recognition-base/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/tensor_types").NamedTensorMap) => { ...; }'.
    Types of parameters 'weightMap' and 'weightMap' are incompatible.
      Type 'import("D:/am workspace/codemeet-frontend - Copy/node_modules/tfjs-image-recognition-base/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/tensor_types").NamedTensorMap' is not assignable to type 'import("D:/am workspace/codemeet-frontend - Copy/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/tensor_types").NamedTensorMap'.
node_modules/face-api.js/build/commonjs/xception/TinyXception.d.ts(10,15): error TS2416: Property 'extractParamsFromWeigthMap' in type 'TinyXception' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'NeuralNetwork<TinyXceptionParams>'.
  Type '(weightMap: import("D:/am workspace/codemeet-frontend - Copy/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/tensor_types").NamedTensorMap) => { params: import("D:/am workspace/codemeet-frontend - Copy/node_modules/face-api.js/build/commonjs/xception/types").TinyXceptionParams; paramMappings: import("D:/am workspace/codemee...' is not assignable to type '(weightMap: import("D:/am workspace/codemeet-frontend - Copy/node_modules/tfjs-image-recognition-base/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/tensor_types").NamedTensorMap) => { ...; }'.
    Types of parameters 'weightMap' and 'weightMap' are incompatible.
      Type 'import("D:/am workspace/codemeet-frontend - Copy/node_modules/tfjs-image-recognition-base/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/tensor_types").NamedTensorMap' is not assignable to type 'import("D:/am workspace/codemeet-frontend - Copy/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/tensor_types").NamedTensorMap'.

Webpack compilation complete. Watching for file changes.
Webpack build done!
nativescript-plugin-firebase: building for same environment, not forcing prepare.
Project successfully prepared (android)
Configure firebase
Copy D:\am workspace\codemeet-frontend - Copy\App_Resources\Android\google-services.json to D:\am workspace\codemeet-frontend - Copy\platforms\android\app\google-services.json.
Successfully transferred bundle.js on device 2bd03de59805.
Successfully transferred runtime.js on device 2bd03de59805.
Successfully transferred vendor.js on device 2bd03de59805.
Restarting application on device 2bd03de59805...
JS: HMR: Hot Module Replacement Enabled. Waiting for signal.
Successfully synced application com.am.sm on device 2bd03de59805.
System.err: An uncaught Exception occurred on "main" thread.
System.err: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.am.sm/com.tns.NativeScriptActivity}: com.tns.NativeScriptException: 
Calling js method onCreate failed
System.err: Error: Main entry is missing. App cannot be started. Verify app bootstrap.
System.err:
System.err: StackTrace:
System.err: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.am.sm/com.tns.NativeScriptActivity}: com.tns.NativeScriptException: Calling js method onCreate failed
System.err: Error: Main entry is missing. App cannot be started. Verify app bootstrap.
System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2925)
System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3060)
System.err:     at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
System.err:     at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
System.err:     at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1818)
System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6762)
System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
**System.err: Caused by: com.tns.NativeScriptException: Calling js method onCreate failed**
**System.err: Error: Main entry is missing. App cannot be started. Verify app bootstrap.**
System.err:     at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodNative(Native Method)
System.err:     at com.tns.Runtime.dispatchCallJSMethodNative(Runtime.java:1242)
System.err:     at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodImpl(Runtime.java:1122)
System.err:     at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:1109)
System.err:     at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:1089)
System.err:     at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:1081)
System.err:     at com.tns.NativeScriptActivity.onCreate(NativeScriptActivity.java:19)
System.err:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7136)
System.err:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7127)
System.err:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1272)
System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2905)
System.err:     ... 11 more
```

**Package.json**

```
"dependencies": {
   "@angular/animations": "8.0.0",
   "@angular/common": "8.0.0",
   "@angular/compiler": "8.0.0",
   "@angular/core": "8.0.0",
   "@angular/fire": "^5.4.0",
   "@angular/forms": "8.0.0",
   "@angular/http": "8.0.0-beta.10",
   "@angular/platform-browser": "8.0.0",
   "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "8.0.0",
   "@angular/router": "8.0.0",
   "@nativescript/schematics": "^0.6.0",
   "@nstudio/nativescript-checkbox": "^1.0.0",
   "@uirouter/angular": "^2.0.0",
   "angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.10",
   "brace": "^0.11.1",
   "core-js": "^2.5.4",
   "face-api.js": "^0.20.0",
   "firebase": "^5.0.4",
   "firepad": "^1.5.1",
   "jquery": "^3.3.1",
   "nativescript-angular": "8.0.2",
   "nativescript-clipboard": "^1.2.0",
   "nativescript-exit": "^1.0.1",
   "nativescript-iqkeyboardmanager": "^1.5.1",
   "nativescript-mediafilepicker": "^2.0.18",
   "nativescript-permissions": "^1.3.8",
   "nativescript-plugin-firebase": "^10.3.3",
   "nativescript-simple-permissions": "^1.0.0",
   "nativescript-theme-core": "~1.0.4",
   "nativescript-toasts": "^1.0.3",
   "nativescript-twilio-video": "^1.1.6",
   "nativescript-urlhandler": "^1.3.0",
   "nativescript-volume": "^1.0.7",
   "ng2-ace-editor": "^0.3.7",
   "ngx-malihu-scrollbar": "^7.0.0",
   "node-sass": "^4.13.1",
   "reflect-metadata": "~0.1.12",
   "rxjs": "^6.2.1",
   "tns-core-modules": "6.0.1",
   "twilio": "^3.31.1",
   "twilio-video": "^1.18.1",
   "zone.js": "0.9.1"
 },
 "devDependencies": {
   "nativescript-dev-webpack": "1.0.1",
   "@nativescript/schematics": "~0.4.0",
   "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "0.800.3",
   "@angular/cli": "~7.1.4",
   "@angular/compiler-cli": "8.0.0",
   "@angular/language-service": "^7.1.4",
   "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.5",
   "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
   "@types/node": "~10.12.18",
   "codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
   "jasmine": "^3.1.0",
   "jasmine-core": "~3.3.0",
   "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
   "karma": "~3.1.4",
   "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
   "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.0",
   "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
   "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.1.0",
   "protractor": "~5.4.2",
   "ts-node": "~7.0.1",
   "tslint": "~5.12.0",
   "typescript": "3.4.5"
 },
 "nativescript": {
   "id": "com.am.sm",
   "tns-android": {
     "version": "6.0.0"
   },
   "tns-ios": {
     "version": "6.0.1"
   }
 }
```

Comment: Please share the sample project where issue can be reproduced.

Comment: got the same error while updating angular to v8 from v7 in different branch only for webapplication. Unable to replicate the error in sample project and also can't share company code base.